# Show that a trapezoid is cyclic if and only if it is isosceles

Tags: geometry

> Show that a trapezoid is cyclic if and only if it is isosceles.

I'm new to geometry and only studied the basics, this problem appered in a chapter about Cyclic Quadrilaterals. Could you give me a hint or solution?

Comment: What properties do you know about cyclic quadrilaterals? What properties do you know about trapezoids (and what makes them isosceles)? As a hint: I'm specifically interested in what you know about *angle* properties. ... The more you can say, the less likely it is for someone to needlessly spend time explaining things you already understand.

Comment: Can you do the forward direction? i.e. show that IF a trapezoid is isosceles, then it is cyclic. This I think is the easier of the two implications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trapezoid always has one pair of parallel sides.

[image]

(image not to scale)

For isosceles $\implies$ cyclic, "isosceles" means $\angle C = \angle D$. By the property of co-interior angles, $\angle A + \angle D = 180º, \angle B + \angle C = 180º$. Write each angle in terms of one angle (say angle $D$), and add all the angles up.

For cyclic $\implies$ isosceles, by the definition of "cyclic", $\angle A + \angle C = \angle B + \angle D = 180º$. However, $\angle A + \angle D = \angle B + \angle C = 180º$ again. Now equate the two statements to get $\angle A + \angle C = \angle A + \angle D$, and the conclusion follows.